# Logging: how can I stop proccesing Critical messages by Warning handler?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

For example: warning message is delivered to the users and the developer and critical message only to the developer. Everything is written to the log file. Currently, the critical message is sent by both warning and critical handler. I'd like to use just one logger, is it possible?
Thank you for the help in advance.

```
import logging
import logging.handlers

main_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
main_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

logHandlerFile = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILE, maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=2, encoding='utf-8')
logHandlerFile.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logHandlerFile.setFormatter(formatter)

logHandlerEmailWarning = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost = MAILHOST, 
                                               fromaddr = SEND_ALERT_FROM,
                                               toaddrs = SEND_WARNING_ALERT_TO,
                                               subject = 'Warning in Digital Data Import!',
                                               credentials = None,
                                               secure = None)
logHandlerEmailWarning.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logHandlerEmailWarning.setFormatter(formatter)

logHandlerEmailCritical = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost = MAILHOST, 
                                                      fromaddr = SEND_ALERT_FROM,
                                                      toaddrs = SEND_ERROR_ALERT_TO,
                                                      subject = 'Error in Digital Data Import!',
                                                      credentials = None,
                                                      secure = None)
logHandlerEmailCritical.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
logHandlerEmailCritical.setFormatter(formatter)

handlers = (logHandlerFile, logHandlerEmailWarning, logHandlerEmailCritical)
for handler in handlers:
    main_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found simple solution by adding Filter object to Handler:

```
class WarningFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, rec):
        return rec.levelno == logging.WARNING


logHandlerEmailWarning.addFilter(WarningFilter())
```